# how to export 2 different size images of a image in java

Tags: java, image, swing, actionevent

My java code below uses a jswing to display a image. When the user fires actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) I want two images exported in sizes 400 X 400 and 300 X 300. So it will be 2 separate images not just one. I don't know I have to write a separate func to do this.

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import javax.swing.*;


   public class Listener extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


private JLabel label1,label2;

public Listener(){
    setTitle("Question");
    JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();
    Panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
    Panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));


     JLabel myButton1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/zman/Desktop/dropIn/e.png"));


    JButton myButton2 = new JButton("2:Export");





    myButton2.addActionListener(this);


    Panel2.add(myButton1);
    Panel2.add(myButton2);


    Panel1.add(Panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(Panel1);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(320, 240);

    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Listener();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into steps:

1. Get the `Image` from the `ImageIcon`
2. Use the `Image.getScaledInstance(…)` method to scale the image to the desired size
3. Use `ImageIO` to write the `Image` to a file.

Since you want two images, I would suggest you create a method and pass the width, height and filename to the method.